# jQuery on click event function to be used as a normal function as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a event handler method which executes on the click of a button. I also pass on some data as shown below

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", {name: "Hello"}, greet );
```

And the method is defined as:

```
function greet(event) {
    // Use the data as event.data.name
    // Access the DOM element on whose click this method was invoked as $(this)
}
```

But I also want to use this function as a normal js function.

1. How do I pass on the data `({name: "Namaskara"})`?
2. How to set the context - For example say I have another button as `<button id="kannada" />` and I want to use this button as the context and be sent to the `greet()` function so that the `$(this)` used in the function would actually be by button

Comment: What does "normal js function" mean? What makes the current `greet` function abnormal?

Comment: agreed with Vohuman what is the issue with this? Have you put your `click` event in `.ready()` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1).** To answer your first question.

> But I also want to use this function as a normal js function. How do I pass on the data 
>  {name: "Namaskara"}?":

You would need to pass in an object with `data` property:

```
greet({data: {name: "Namaskara"}});
```

**2).** The second question about context:

```
var $kannada = $('#kannada'); // another button
greet.call($kannada[0], {data: {name: "Namaskara"}});
```

In this case `greet` will be invoked like if you manually clicked `#kannada` button, meaning that context `this` will be pointing to `button#kannada`. Of course in this case event object inside `greet` will not be real mouse event, but it will have `data` property properly set.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ddhzwk43/

Comment: I got this answer as the base for my solution and it worked. I like the idea of greet.call used here to change the context and also the event.data to pass on the data

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    otherfunction('Namaskara');
});

function otherfunction(name){
    //do something here with the name :)
    alert(name);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wzbphgyv/

Updated with your ID thing inside:

http://jsfiddle.net/wzbphgyv/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    second_function('param_data1', 'param_data2');
});

function second_function(getParam1, getParam2){
    alert(getParam1 + getParam2);
}
```

[Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/b8kkjqdw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

No need for second function mapping use proxy instead:

```
function greet(name){
   console.log(name);
}
var proxy = $.proxy(greet, this, "hello"); 

$("#test").on("click", proxy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `data-*` html5 attribute to hold specific data to utilize. You can do something like this:

#### HTML:

```
<button data-name="Hello">click</button>
<button id="kannada" data-name="Namaskara">kannada</button>
```

#### jQuery:

```
function greet() {
    alert($(this).data('name')); // alerts - Hello for button 1
}                                // alerts - kannada for button 2
$(function () {
    $("button").on("click", greet);
});
```

### [Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u06jp8fz/)